# How does Eclipse detect errors in code

Tags: java, eclipse

I wonder how Eclipse detects errors in Java code before compiling it.

I've found [this answer](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/645745/) from the Eclipse forums which mentions reconciliation. But that doesn't tell me how it works.

Is the error and warning detection done by comparing the code with the Java specification using regular expressions?

Comment: It probably tries to compile it in a background thread and parses the errors it gets.

Comment: @Keppil: I can't imagine that. Compiling larger code can take minutes to hours. The IDE's feedback to a new line of code is practically instant.

Comment: @mareser: I dont think IDE compiles all codes. It just need to compile the changed code. There might be some way that it traces what have changed and what is the influence of the change. But i'm only guessing.

Comment: just observationally, it behaves as though it maintains an imaginary compiled set that includes all the changes made but not saved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you change something in your code, the changes are represented as deltas. The deltas get analyzed by creating the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) and [JDT](https://www.eclipse.org/jdt/overview.php) looks for errors. If there are any, then the error markers are generated.

[Here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/Overview_of_Parsing) is a good explanation how CDT parser for C/C++ works. The JDT parser should be working the same way.